# Javascript implementation of arrows in input number - How to make so that changes concerned each item?

Tags: javascript

I have a basket of goods in which there can be many different entities. And I'm trying to implement changes in the number of goods using `input - number` without arrows, and with additional buttons `+/-`. I know that I could use `identifiers` and easily make my plans. But in my case, I need to use `querySelectorAll`. Help me please correct this code. `quantity-arrow-minus` decreases the field value and `quantity-arrow-plus` increases. How to make it so that the changes are concerned with each item?

```js
var minus = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity-arrow-minus');
var update_cart = document.querySelectorAll('.update_cart');
var plus = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity-arrow-plus');

minus.forEach(function(node) {
node.addEventListener('click', function() {
    update_cart.forEach(function(element) {
        element.value = parseInt(element.value) - 1;
    });
});
});

plus.forEach(function(node) {
node.addEventListener('click', function() {
    update_cart.forEach(function(element) {
        element.value = parseInt(element.value) + 1;
    });
});
});
```

```html
<form method="GET">
<button type="button" class="quantity-arrow-minus">-</button>
<input type="number" class="update_cart" value="1">
<button type="button" class="quantity-arrow-plus">+</button>
</form>

<form method="GET">
<button type="button" class="quantity-arrow-minus">-</button>
<input type="number" class="update_cart" value="1">
<button type="button" class="quantity-arrow-plus">+</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Try: `element.value = parseInt(update_cart.value) - 1;`

Comment: @NullDev, same error :(

Comment: You should be using `parseInt(element.value)` not `update_cart.value`

Comment: The browser warning is probably coming from the `{{item.quantity}}` value; did you check it was not a NaN?

Comment: I agree with Pointy, but on top of that, the code as you've written it will decrease / increase the value for all elements

Comment: @Pointy, oh, it helped me, but now all my fields change

Comment: @MichaelBeeson, yes, it's true. But how make each value changing? just every product has this form and I do not know how to make everyone change

Comment: If you could make a snippet with simplified, working, code, we could help easily. The key is you need to have your 'minus' node identify the 'update_cart' input associated with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [previousElementSibling and nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode#Properties) to access the input that corresponds to the button that was clicked:

```js
var minus = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity-arrow-minus');
var update_cart = document.querySelectorAll('.update_cart');
var plus = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity-arrow-plus');

minus.forEach(function(node) {
    node.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
       const input = e.target.nextElementSibling
       input.value = parseInt(input.value) - 1;
    });
});

plus.forEach(function(node) {
    node.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
       const input = e.target.previousElementSibling
       input.value = parseInt(input.value) + 1;
    });
});
```

```html
<form action="{% url 'cart:cart_update' %}" method="GET">
    <button type="button" class="quantity-arrow-minus">-</button>
    <input type="number" class="update_cart" value="0">
    <button type="button" class="quantity-arrow-plus">+</button>
    <br>
    <button type="button" class="quantity-arrow-minus">-</button>
    <input type="number" class="update_cart" value="0">
    <button type="button" class="quantity-arrow-plus">+</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Number()` instead. Assuming that the minus button will be just after your input, just use `this.nextElementSibling`. This is will make your code better instead of doing forEach on every element. What if there are many elements like these?

```js
var minus = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity-arrow-minus');
var plus = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity-arrow-plus');

minus.forEach((node) => {
   node.onclick = function () {
       this.nextElementSibling.value = Number(this.nextElementSibling.value) - 1;
   }
});

plus.forEach((node) => {
    node.onclick = function () {
       this.previousElementSibling.value =Number(this.previousElementSibling.value) + 1;
   }
});
```

```html
<button class="quantity-arrow-minus">-</button>
<input type="number" class="update_cart" value="1">
<button class="quantity-arrow-plus">+</button>
<br>
<button class="quantity-arrow-minus">-</button>
<input type="number" class="update_cart" value="1">
<button class="quantity-arrow-plus">+</button>
<br>
<button class="quantity-arrow-minus">-</button>
<input type="number" class="update_cart" value="1">
<button class="quantity-arrow-plus">+</button>
```